# select case with subquery returns multiple line in select

Tags: sql, oracle

I use select case to return a value depending on a condition, but in some cases, the subquery select returs more then one line, so I get an error.

The goal is to let the function  return a 0 or 1 based on certain condition.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN my_count <= 1 AND stat = "START" THEN 0
            WHEN my_count > 1 AND stat IN ("START", "RUN", "ERR") THEN 1
            ELSE -1
       END AS
INTO return_val
FROM (select
     (SELECT count(DISTINCT(stat) FROM my_table
     WHERE my_table.HIVE = "hive1"
     AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE("20190605", 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
       AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE("20190605", 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
   ) status_count,
     (SELECT DISTINCT(status) AS status_ FROM my_table
     WHERE EL_F_BDP_PROC_REALTIME.HIVE = "hive1"
     AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE("20190605", 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
       AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE("20190605", 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
   )status_
     FROM dual
       )x    ;
      RETURN(return_val);
END;
```

Comment: You are working with one table. Can using analitics funstion with statement 'over partition by'

Comment: error in current reduction in  (SELECT DISTINCT(status) AS status_ FROM my_table
     WHERE EL_F_BDP_PROC_REALTIME.HIVE = "hive1"
     AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE("20190605", 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
       AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE("20190605", 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
   ) may be agregate snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few status in statement:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT(status) AS status_ FROM my_table 
          WHERE EL_F_BDP_PROC_REALTIME.HIVE = 'hive1' 
          AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
          AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
        )
```

and returned more one line.

For rigth execute you need return one value example:

```
max((SELECT DISTINCT(status) AS status_ FROM my_table 
              WHERE EL_F_BDP_PROC_REALTIME.HIVE = 'hive1' 
              AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
              AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('20191212', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
            ))
```

Is it executing, but ,purhaps ,logic is wrong

Try it:

```
with tbl as (
select 'START' status,     'hive1' str, to_date('2019-12-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd') dt from dual 
union all
select 'NA' status,     'hive1' str, to_date('2019-12-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual 
union all
select 'END' status,     'hive1' str, to_date('2019-12-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual)
select dt, str, listagg(status, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY str) 
from tbl
GROUP BY dt, str
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your query has several syntax issues. You need to :

- change your double-quotes to single-quotes
- fix date format ( `20190605` isn't compatible with `YYYY-MM-DD` )
- there's a missing parentheses after `count(DISTINCT(stat)`
- if a `case when .. then` expression is followed by an `as`, that `as`
  should be followed by an (valid) alias
- I suppose `my_count` stands for `status_count` within the
  `case..when` expression
- Alias `status_` in `DISTINCT(status) AS status_` is redundant, and
  has no sense

So, Consider the following SELECT statement :

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN status_count <= 1 AND status_ = 'START' THEN
          0
         WHEN status_count > 1 AND status_ IN ('START', 'RUN', 'ERR') THEN
          1
         ELSE
          -1
       END 
  INTO :return_val
  FROM (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT stat)
                  FROM my_table
                 WHERE my_table.HIVE = 'hive1'
                   AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) =
                       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE'2019-06-05')
                   AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) =
                       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE'2019-06-05')) status_count,
               (SELECT MAX(DISTINCT status)
                  FROM my_table
                 WHERE EL_F_BDP_PROC_REALTIME.HIVE = 'hive1'
                   AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARTITION_DATE) =
                       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE'2019-06-05')
                   AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARTITION_DATE) =
                       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE'2019-06-05')) status_
          FROM dual);
```

Your problem related to returning more than one row might be due to the part `DISTINCT(status) AS status_` where you can use an aggregation such as `MIN` or `MAX` to return exactly one row within that subquery, by converting to `MAX(DISTINCT status)`